# Database ResultSet get String/Integer with SELECT

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to know what the number X needs to be in order to receive the data properly.

Example code :

```
Statement sta = (connection object).createStatement();

sta.executeQuery("SELECT 'points' FROM TABLEX WHERE 'player'='" + player_name + "'").getString(X); ///HERE
```

Comment: Even if you get an answer it is not going to work, as you first need to call `next()` on the `ResultSet` before you can retrieve a value. Please consult a [proper JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) and the API documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either 1, or "points" will work.

1 is the index of the column as specified in the select statement.  The indexing starts from 1 and increments from there.

Otherwise the name of the column may be used, in this case "points".  That method may cause a bit more meta data to get loaded and so performance can vary.

Comment: That is not going to work without a call to `next()`, which is missing in the code of the question.

Comment: There is a lot of the boiler plate that is also missing, not just next().  I took it that Zarkopafilis was asking a very specific question about getString.  I am happy to update the answer if that is not the case.

Comment: Technically upto the `getString` call everything is fine (assuming `(connection object)` is meant to leave out connection creation).

Answer (score 2):

As the **javadoc** says :

```
getString(int columnIndex)
```

Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language. and

```
getString(String columnLabel)
```

Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.

So this is not going to work. It will give you :

`java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set`

First of all you need to iterate through the `Resultset` obtained using `next()` then you can retrieve the specific values by either pass `1` which is the column index in this case or `points` which is the columnName of your table and based on the `where clause` it shall give you different values of the column `points`

Comment: That is not going to work without a call to `next()`, which is missing in the code of the question.

Comment: Oh yes my mistake updating it.

Answer (score 0):

X is the column number(index) in the table.

It is needed to fetch the data from table.

You also can use `column name` instead of `column index` like this -

```
getString(ColumnName);
```